# Python: base class for all other classes

Tags: python

In Python, what is the base class for all other classes (real Base), that all other classes inherit from?

Comment: its funny we have similar names ^^

Comment: Nope. A complicated Python simulation says something different: `print "Jakub"=="Jakob"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All new style classes inherit from `object`.

New-style classes were introduced in Python 2.2 to unify classes and types. [Here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/whatsnew/sect-rellinks.html) there is a nice description of what a new style class is. – Paolo Moretti

Comment: New-style classes were introduced in Python 2.2 to unify classes and types. [Here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/whatsnew/sect-rellinks.html) there is a nice description of what a new style class is.

Answer (score 1):

It is `object`. At least in 2.7 and 3.1.

```
>>> class A():
...     pass
... 
>>> isinstance(A, object)
True
```

Comment: this surprised me.. how, then, is a `class B(object): pass` different from class A?  I get `<__main__.A instance at ...>` and `<__main__.B object at ...>` !

Comment: It's a compatibility workaround because new-style classes were introduced in the middle of Python 2 and they couldn't break the old functionality. In Python 3 you no longer need to include the explicit `object inheritance.

Comment: On Python2, if you inherit from object, you create a new style class. On Python3, all classes are new style( https://gist.github.com/d2ded62e5f885d61ff75 ). And look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/ for differences between old and new style classes.

Comment: eeeish, what an ugly wrinkle!  then again, i guess pythons do have vestigial legs inside their bodies..

Comment: Indeed it is ugly and that's one of the things Python 3 addresses.